como hago que mi opcion de regreso funcione?
Tengo mi codigo ya terminado para jugar piedra papel o tijeras, solo que debo ponerle la opcion de retorno cada que ingrese un numero que no esta dentro del espectro mostrado; a lo que me indique que no es valido y me regrese para elegir otro. Mi pregunta es como puedo hacer para mi opcion de regreso funcione?
Estoy en c++
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>
#include<time.h>    
int main(){
    int player, compu, again;
    int win=0, lost=0, tie=0;
    srand(time(0));
    
    do{
    printf("Quieres jugar?\n");
    printf("1: Piedra\n2: Papel:\n3: Tijeras \n");
    
    printf("Elije un numero:");
    scanf("%d",&player);
    
    if(player<1||player>3){
        printf("No valido. ELije 1, 2 o 3.\n");
        return 1;
    }
    
    compu=rand()%3+1;
    printf("Elegiste: %d\n", player);
    printf("La computadora eligio: %d\n", compu);
    
    if(player==compu){
        tie++;
        printf("Empate\n");
    }else if( (player==1&&compu==3)||
              (player==2&&compu==1)||
              (player==3&&compu==2) ){
                win++;
                printf("GANASTE!!!\n");
    }else{
        lost++;
        printf("Perdiste :( \n");
    }
    printf("\n Marcador\n");
    printf("==================\n");
    printf("|%-10s | %2d |\n", "Victorias:", win);
    printf("|%-10s | %2d |\n", "Derrotas:", lost);  
    printf("|%-10s | %2d |\n", "Empates:", tie);
    printf("==================\n\n\n");
    
    
    printf("Quieres volver a jugar? 1→Si, 2→No:");
    scanf("%d",&again);
    
}while(again==1);           
}


en la descripción dices que el código es en C++ pero esta enteramente escrito en C. Para lo que quieres hacer, lo mejor es utilizar un switch - case, y que una de las opciones sea terminar/salir, suponiendo que la opción salir es el 4, el while seria: while(opcion != 4); y en el switch - case, el case default sería "opcion no valida". Si no te aclaras con esto te pongo una respuesta más amplia con código.

Implemente un bucle infinito arriba de su validación if (player >= 1 && player <= 3) ..
while (true) {  // bucle
    printf("Elige un número: ");
    scanf("%d", &player);
    if (player >= 1 && player <= 3) {
        break; // si no es de acuerdo con las opciones, permanecerá en bucle
    } else {
        printf("No válido. Elige 1, 2 o 3.\n");
    }
}

Al final, añade una línea que retorne 0,
que es para informar que el programa ha terminado.
} while (again == 1);           

return 0;

Y necesitarás usar include <stdbool.h>.
